Will exposure to rain damage my batteries?
I have these batteries in my home solar setup. When it rains, they get wet. Is it a problem ?

Edit:


Can you put another photo showing the model number of the batteries? I assume all 4 are of same brand and model.

Yes, Phoenix tx-3500
280 ah 12 volt each

Schematic, please ...

Please [edit] and  put any additional info in the question and not in the comments, that is not what they are for. Thanks.

We can't tell is this is ok or not without knowing what and how these batteries are connected to.

Those metal connectors will corrode and cause bad contacts given time. Bad contacts get hot and will cause the voltage to drop.

@Antonio51
Sorry, I don't have schematics.

@RJR Batteries are connected to 8 KW inverter.

In general there are no major problems with low voltage robust equipment getting wet - with exceptions!
With DC you may get electrolysis and hydrogen oxygen mixture. Bad in a confined space.
The water may cause corrosion of any metals.
It can damage exposed electronics
If the water builds up and floods then electrolysis and (possibly) boiling water is an issue
Just take simple precautions against water ingress

You can't say that without knowing what the batteries are connected to. If the equipment they are connected to expects one side of the batteries to be grounded, or worse, mains-referenced, the rain will cause all kind of problems.

If it actually floods, yes, it will probably cause damage to your batteries. It could also become a fire hazard, mitigated only by the rain that's falling.
That said, some water just falling on top would generally not cause much damage if your connectors are rated for ourdoor use.
In general, though, I would strongly recommend you cover it so that water doesn't fall directly on the batteries. Water pooling around the batteries is also preferable to avoid if possible, usually done by elevating the batteries a couple of inches atleast.

Same as above - You can't say that without knowing what the batteries are connected to. If the equipment they are connected to expects one side of the batteries to be grounded, or worse, mains-referenced, the rain will cause all kind of problems.

l agree, but the question was about whether it will damage batteries. The likelihood of the OP being able to provide a schematic is low, and the question does deserve an answer. I chose to answer it based on what the typical solar installation usually looks like.

@ChintalagiriShashank please define "typical solar installation".

In this context, batteries are connected to an inverter and charge controller which is subsequently connected to mains. These are generally off the shelf components which will trip or fuse out if something goes very wrong.
